# Is there a way to make an "intelligent" desktop object that filters a specific target folder's children on whether they contain a certain subfolder?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Let's say we have the following folder hierarchy in Windows 10:

```
  data
    acme widgets
       2022
       2023
       2024
    gizmos
        2023
    etc1
    etc2
    ...
    etc999
```

There are hundreds of sibling folders at the "acme widgets" and "gizmos" level in the hierarchy, some of which will contain a 2024 folder, like *acme widgets*, and some of which won't, like *gizmos*. But those that don't have a *2024* folder will at some point have it added to their subfolders, and at some point one or more files will be added to the *2024* folder. At that point I need to take some action.

So I would like to be able to click on a desktop icon that displays a folder listing (ideally a navigable one) only of those folders beneath folder *data* that contain a *2024* subfolder with one or more files in it. There's no way to predict what those files would be named. Can such an intelligent desktop icon be created using Power Shell?  If yes, what functions (i.e. command-names) would I need to come up to speed on?

FWIW, I'm working with folders and files stored in such a hierarchy which is being maintained by someone else, and they don't let me know when a 2024 folder has been created in one of those child folders or when files have been added to it.

I would prefer not to add any sort of "listener" to the folder hierarchy; just a filtering mechanism of some kind would suffice.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Do note, SuperUser is not a "please write me a script" kind of service. If you post us the script you already have, we can help you with why its not working. A few commands that you'd want is `get-childitem -recurse` and  `get-date -format "yyyy"`

Comment: @LPChip I understand. That's why I asked not for a script but for the functions (i.e. the names of the commands)  I'd have to come up to speed on.  I haven't written such a script but need a start in the right direction.  I will make that clearer. Thanks for the get-childitem tip.

Comment: If you edit the question with a script that you've come up with, we can help you. Currenty its hard to gauge how much of a programmers mindset you have. Here is something to get started: `$files = get-childitem -path C:\ -recurse` `$files | foreach-object { write-host $_.Name }` `if ( $_.Name -eq get-date -format "yyyy") { #we have a 2024 folder }`

Comment: You could more simply just search for a `2024` folder. An excellent utility for that is [voidtools Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

Comment: The person maintaining the data often creates a 2024 folder well in advance (days, even weeks) of putting files in the folder. So I have to find non-empty 2024 folders, that is, those containing one or more user-created files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **PowerShell**, defining the search is relatively trivial. To consolidate the results into a browseable collection, I like to use folder shortcuts, a sort of shell-only directory junction, which behave like a true folder.

*EDIT: Explanation follows code and instructions below*
*EDIT2: Code "tightened" with specifying `-LiteralPath`
wherever it's available*

Copy the code into **Notepad** and save as a `.ps1` file:

```
$DataPath     = 'C:\Path\to\Data'
$filteredPath = "$env:Temp\FiiteredData"
# Start fresh each run
If (Test-Path -LiteralPath $filteredPath) {
    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $filteredPath -Recurse -Force
}
mkdir $FilteredPath | out-null

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $DataPath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 |
  where name -eq '2024' | where {Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File} | ForEach-Object {
    # Setting the ReadOnly attribute for a folder enables desktop.ini processing 
    ($newFolder                = mkdir (Join-Path $FilteredPath $_.Parent.Name)).Attributes += 'ReadOnly'
    $TargetShortcut            = (New-Object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut("$NewFolder\Target.lnk")
    $TargetShortcut.TargetPath = $_.Parent.FullName
    $TargetShortcut.Save()
    # Tells the shell to link to the contents of Target.lnk
    "[.ShellClassInfo]`nCLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}`nFlags=2`n`n" | Set-Content "$newFolder\desktop.ini"
}
# Open EXplorer to our folder populated with folder shortcuts
Invoke-Item -LiteralPath $FilteredPath
```

Then, on your Desktop:

1. Right-click, `New >` -> `Shortcut`
2. Type `PowerShell -File '<path to .ps1 file>'`
3. Click `Next`, name it whatever you like, and `Finish`.

**Note:** If you've never run **PowerShelll** scripts on your machine, you will probably need to modify the [ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.4). To do so, open a Windows PowerShell console and type:

- `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

and you're good to go.

---

The logic:

- Get the Directeryinfo objects for the top-level folders (company name)and their subfolders (year)

  - `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $DataPath -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1`
- Filter on `Name` to select only folders named "2024" (the company folder can be accessed as a property of this folder)

  - `where name -eq '2024'`
- Then filter those based on whether or not they contain any files (`[Bool](Get-ChildItem -File)` is false if the folder contains no files)
- `where {Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File}`
- When a folder meets the filter criteria, create a *Folder Shortcut* to its parent folder (company name)

*...and just what is a Folder Shortcut?*

One of the best tricks of the Windows Shell. At the filesytem level, it consists of a folder, the name of which will be the display name of the shortcut. The folder contains two files, a "Target.lnk" file which is an "ordinary" shortcut to the target folder, and a "desktop.ini" with the magical incantation:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID2={0AFACED1-E828-11D1-9187-B532F1E9575D}
Flags=2
```

- The shell will not process a folder's desktop.ini file unless the folder's ReadOnly attribute is set. It can only be set or cleared via code, not that misleading checkbox in the Properties dialog. It's status can only be accessed via code or the `Attributes` column in an EXplorer Details view, not that misleading checkbox in the Properties dialog.

When the attribute is set, the folder displays the contents of the target folder as if it were it's own -- a namespace junction. Note that the shortcut itself can be deleted without affecting the contents of the target, but the *contents* of the shortcut are the contents of the target -- item creation, editing, and deletion from either location will be seen in the other because they are the same item.

Rferences:

- [CreateShortcut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)

Comment: Thanks. I'm out of the office but will try this out. Do I understand correctly what is happening?  The original hierarchy is traversed, looking two levels deep for the 2024 folder, and for each file of a 2024 folder when one is encountered there is a virtual link created in the temporary directory; and at the end, the file explorer shell is fed the ini file for the temporary directory, to display the file listing.  Is that right?

Comment: When I try it, a command window is opened and immediately closed. When creating the shortcut, I included the full path in single quotes:  `PowerShell -File 'h:\my\SearchTest.ps1'`   and I've set the ExecutionPolicy as indicated and was asked to confirm, and received a success message.  The command window appears to be empty, and the underscore cursor is in the top left corner.

Comment: I've also tried editing script so that `$FilteredPath` points to "h:\FilteredData" and the directory isn't being created.

Comment: Thanks. It will be a learning exercise for me, since I've not tried any PowerShell scripting.

Comment: It works perfectly well when pasted into PowerShell.

Comment: And if I right-click on the script file, and choose Run in Powershell, that works too.

Comment: I'm a happy camper with that. Thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the updates -- I hate waking up to "...not working.."-- LoL! With the script working, hope you're inspored to get it running from shortuct when you get a chance; and hope you're inspired to learn more PowerShell!

Comment: If/when you troubleshoot running from a shortcut, start by editing the PowerShell invokation by adding the `-NoExit` parameter as the first parameter in teh call; i.e. `PowerShell -NoExit -File '<path to .ps1 file>'`. That prevents the window from closing when the script completes so you can see posible error messages, etc.